# Caret - Train does not provide Accuracy SD to nnet model output

Tags: r, r-caret, nnet

I am trying to train neural network model using the function "train" in "caret" package. But it gives a lot of warnings and does not show the accuracy SD. I am not sure if I have to set any parameters so that I can see the Accuracy SD.

I am relatively new to R so please excuse me if I am missing on something that is obvious.

Here is my code:

```
library("caret", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
set.seed(1056)
nnetFit <- train(Label ~., data = Train_2.4.16,
                 method = "nnet",
                 preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                 tuneLength = 5,
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                                      repeats = 5))
nnetFit
```

Below is a sample of the warnings that I get on executing the code:

> 49: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :   model fit failed for Fold10.Rep1:
>   size=9, decay=1e-03 Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, softmax = TRUE,
>   ...) :    too many (1049) weights
>
> 50: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :   model fit failed for Fold10.Rep1:
>   size=9, decay=1e-04 Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, softmax = TRUE,
>   ...) :    too many (1049) weights*

The output of the code lists the neural network size, the decay, the Accuracy and Kappa.

I would also appreciate it if you can help me understand what is the decay and the kappa.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the `MaxNWts` argument to the [`nnet`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nnet/versions/7.3-12/topics/nnet) function. Can can pass that argument to `train` and it will get to `nnet`.